# Token generation on the server side in next js

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm currently using next.js' server side rendering to fetch APIs on the server side, but i have an issue where those APIs need a token that will will expire every 1 hour, and the issue is I can't save the token or the expiry date on local storage or cookies because the server side doesn't have access to these things at all, what is the best way to handle this case? (Note that there is an API that I'm using to generate tokens).

Comment: how are you making the api? (app router? pages api? server action? or ...?)

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies on the server side of the NextJS

##### (App Router) Route API

```js
/app/api/get-token/route.js
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  let response = NextResponse.next()

  response.cookies.set('token', 'Bearer abc123')

  return response
}
```

##### (App Router) Server Action

```js
'use server'
 
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
 
export function setToken() {
  cookies().set('token', "abc123")
}
```

##### (Pages Router) Route API

you need to install the 'cookies-next' package first.

###### using npm

`npm i cookies-next`

###### using yarn

`yarn add cookies-next`

```js
/pages/api/set-cookie.js
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next'

export default async function setApiCookie(req, res) {
  try {
    setCookie('token', 'Bearer abc123', { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 })
    res.status(200).send('set api cookies')
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message)
  }
}
```

##### (Pages Router) getServerSideProps

As like previous solution, you need to have the `cookies-next` package installed.

```js
import { setCookie } from 'cookies-next'

export const getServerSideProps = ({ req, res }) => {
  setCookie('token', 'Bearer abc123', { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 })

  return { props: {} }
}
```

I hope that helps. feel free to ask, if you have questions or if you still have problems.

EDIT:
I just created an example for `pages` route as you requested. you can find the source in my github:
https://github.com/arashi-dev/set-cookies-in-nextjs-pages.git

*for users in futures: if the link does not work tell me and I will make another one*

Comment: can you kindly give me a code pen example for this? the folder structure is a little unclear. Thanks! (as i said in my case i have an API that will be used to generate tokens, i must call this API every one hour and update a specific cookie on the server if possible as you mentioned, all the components should have access to this token on the server side so i can  use it in my other API calls)

Comment: @Elias Okay I will add a codesandbox example. but before that, which router are you using? (I mean, are you building your pages inside `pages` folder or `app` folder?)

Comment: Hello, I'm building my pages inside the "pages" folder. Thanks!

Comment: @Elias sorry for the delay. the codesandbox was not let me set cookies. I just added the source code example in github, to the answer :) good luck

Comment: @Elias Hi again. is your problem solved?